# English translation of Ibn Ezra's Torah commentary

Tags: torah-study, jewish-books, commentaries, translation, avraham-ibn-ezra

I'm trying to look for a book with Ibn Ezra's commentary on the Torah, with both Hebrew, and English translations. However, I can't find one. Could anyone recommend a book which has this?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Joseph and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

Hi welcome to Mi Yodeya

Ibn Ezra's commentary on Chumash is available translated into english in this book: [https://www.amazon.com/Ibn-Ezras-Commentary-Pentateuch-Bereshit/dp/0932232078](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0932232078)

> Ibn Ezra, Abraham (1988–2004). Ibn Ezra’s commentary on the
> Pentateuch. Strickman, H. Norman and Silver, Arthur M. (trans.). New
> York: Menorah Publishing.

It is out of print for ages now and very hard to get hold of but you might be able to borrow it from [a library](https://search.worldcat.org/oclc/17875414). You can also find [the whole thing uploaded for free on Sefaria, cross referenced with the Tanach](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.1?lang=en&aliyot=0&p2=Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.1.1.1&lang2=en&w2=About&lang3=en).